# insertar PHP en jquery

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress

Dispongo de grupo de datos en PHP con 5 elementos dentro cada grupo, entre ellos una imagen. Luego dispongo de un vídeo sin póster por que tiene hover to play implementado, el problema es que Safari en dispositivos móviles bloquea esto y se me ha ocurrido la ide ade a partir de 900px añadirle el poster, el código lo tengo casi, pero me añade el póster pero no la imagen, y creo que es por que esta mal hecha la linea. Aquí dejo el código donde contiene los datos. (es usando ACF en wordpress)

```
$preview = get_field('homepage-videos');
```

Y este es el vídeo con el script.

```
<div class="video">
  <video class="thevideo" loop muted>
     <source src="<?php echo $previews['volles-video']; ?>" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="<?php echo $previews['kurzes-video']; ?>" type="video/webm">
     Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
 <script> 
  if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 900) {
      $('.video video').attr('poster', "<?php echo $previews['poster']['sizes']['large']; ?>");
                                }
  </script>
```

Y esto es lo que me muestra el DevTools de chrome

```
<video class="thevideo" loop="" muted="" poster="">
   <source src="http://www.die-lounge.com/test/dlb/wp- 
   content/uploads/2019/01/VerifiableTerrificHind.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="http://www.die-lounge.com/test/dlb/wp- 
   content/uploads/2019/01/VerifiableTerrificHind.webm" type="video/webm">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

¿Alguien me puede indicar que falla a la hora de añadir el póster? Gracias.

**NOTA**

El problema que tengo y el por que quiero poner esto es el siguiente:
El video tiene un sistema de hover to play implementado tipo youtube, el tema es que en responsive no hay hover y lo que hice fue hacer un scrollontop, pero por alguna razón, en safari no muestra los videos, solo se ve un icono que tiene cada video y lo demas en blanco. Entonces mi idea es que para mobiles, se muestre el poster. De hecho lo que quiero hacer es que el poster este inactivo por encima de los 900px y a partir de 900px el poster sea visible, pero no lo logo ni a la de tres.

**NOTA 2**

He intentado saltarme jquery y hacerlo con javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 900)
       var url = "<?php echo $previews['poster']; ?>";
       document.getElementsByClassName("thevideo").poster = url;
});
```

Pero nada, los resultados son los mismos, he probado a poner con doble comilla, con simple comilla, sin comilla **y lo unico que logro es que se añada el atributo poster="" pero la url no va, he hecho console.warn a la url en php y me la da correcta, pero por alguna razon que no entiendo no la añade a la etiqueta poster. Tambien en revisado que variable contenga info con un var_dump, todo correcto. Sin embargo si meto la url de la variable directamente a mano o cualquier otra, me la muestra perfectamente.**

**NOTA 3**

He intentado usando, en vez de attr();, meter background-image por jquery, añadirle una clase con backgroud, usar id´s para referenciar cada elemento que se repite en el foreach...Al final el resultado siempre es el mismo, jquery capta la url, pero lo pasa a html, es decir, si inspecciono el código, veo la url en la función jquery, pero luego en el video tag se refleja poster="" o background-image: url(""). 
Ya no se que hacer

Comment: Asi de primeras, el video tiene la clase `thevideo` y en el jquery buscas la clase `video`

Comment: Vale, es que me falto un div antes con la clase video, lo pongo ya, la clase .thevideo la tengo reservada para una funcion aparte. De todas maneras, si te fijas, el script funciona, lo que no me ñade es la imagene en php que tengo.

Comment: Mira en el inspeccionar de elementos a ver que valor tiene el `<?php echo $previews['poster']['sizes']['large']; ?>;`

Comment: lo primero que hice fue un var_dump y me escupe excatamente la imagen que esta puesta, el tema es que es un foreach, son 5 celdas, de las 5 solo le tengo asignadas 1 para testear, y esta todo en orden ya que me muestra en el div 1 la imagen y luego 4 null, o sea, celdas vacias. Yo se que el fallo erradica la funcion jquery...pero no pillo donde. Obviamente sobra decir que de momento estoy trabajando bajo el codigo no en un archivo aparte js

Comment: Has probado a no entrecomillar `<?php echo $previews['poster']['sizes']['large']; ?>` ?

Comment: Si, pero lo voy a volver a probar, de todas formas creo que tengo el deber de explicar cual es la finalidad por que es muy probable que haya una solucion mas facil. Lo pongo arriba

Comment: Estás llamando mal a la variable $preview, se te ha colado una ese en el echo, tienes $previews en lugar de $preview

Comment: nono, al ser un foreach esta puesto foreach ($preview as previews).

Comment: Es que no es problema de jquery, dado que está poniendo el atributo poster. Es un problema de que esa variable, previews, está vacia. Hazle un var_dump() y mira que tiene dentro. Con el resultado nos dices. Seria interesante ver el foreach y de donde saca los datos.

Comment: La variable previews no esta vacia, dentro de previews, esta el video mp4, el video webm, iconos y un editor, y todo es funcional, de hecho si yo pongo el poster y le meto la variable $previews['poster']['sizes']['large']; muestra la imagen. pero al pasarla por jquery da un error de string en sizes y en large.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91856/discussion-between-emerita-and-dario-b).

Answer (score 1):

Despues de romperme la cabeza, he encontrado la soluciòn. 
He dejado la variable como poster y he implementado esto en mi archivo php:

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 900) {

    $('video').each(function () {
        const poster = $(this).data('poster');
        $(this).attr('poster', poster);
    });
}
```

Gracias a todos los que me habeis intentado ayudar

Comment: Le has metido un data al vídeo y de ahí lo has pasado a attr?